# Is it possible to color only part of a Node?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying  to partially color fill a Pane, but with no success.
What I need to do is, given a percentage, fill out that percentage of the Node  whit color. 
It's not easy to explain so I hope this simple [drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKWsu.png) does it:

What I tried to do is to create a Rectangle with *Pane.Width * Percentage* as its width and finally set the color, but it doesn't work as intended and too complex.

Is there any simple way, using CSS or just JavaFX code to do so?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/help can help you.

Comment: I seriously doublt that there is anything simpler than a binding. This is far from complex though... Not really sure why this isn't working for you; it's impossible to tell without seeing the code... Code could also help us determine why you consider the approach using a binding too complex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best possible solution but it is just a 5 minute effort and it works.

```
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class PercentageColorPane extends Pane {

    double ratio;

    DoubleBinding widthBinding;

    public PercentageColorPane(double percent) {
        assert 0.0 <= percent && percent <= 100.0;
        ratio = 0.01 * percent;

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.setFill(Color.RED);

        widthBinding = widthProperty().multiply(ratio);

        rectangle.setX(0.0);
        rectangle.setY(0.0);
        rectangle.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
        rectangle.widthProperty().bind(widthBinding);

        getChildren().add(rectangle);
    }

}

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PercentageColorPaneDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        PercentageColorPane pane = new PercentageColorPane(30.0);       
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: @fabian Interesting point but could you give an example where this would cause a problem? Pure Panes do not layout their children anyway whether they are managed or not.

Comment: Whops, you're right, `Pane` doesn't do these kind of calculations based on the children; you're absolutely right...